# Freeswitch detect Fax programmatically

Tags: python, freeswitch, fax

I'm currently generating dial outs using "ESL with Python library" and the **originate** command.
Since some dial out calls are **Fax** I need to classify which of these calls are fax, otherwise I record the ones which are normally answered by humans, voice mail or auto-attendants.

I'm using:

```
execute_on_fax_detect
```

As follows:

```
originate {ignore_early_media=true,originate_timeout=20,media_bug_answer_req=True,origination_uuid=4cb6665a-1e2a-4e24-ad71-1602870960d2,origination_caller_id_number=+18623079305,RECORD_STEREO=true,execute_on_fax_detect='txfax /tmp/sample.tif',execute_on_answer='record_session /usr/local/freeswitch/recordings/E6248DD147_8884732963_4ab6665f-1e2a-4e24-ab71-1602870960d2.wav'}sofia/gateway/twilio/+13193412303 &park()
```

Call is answered but I don't see any fax detection kicking in.
I also tried with +18884732963 which is the HP test fax number.
In the recording I can hear the Fax tones.

```
FreeSWITCH (Version 1.7.0 git c9abf45 2016-06-27 22:23:25Z 64bit) is ready
```

**Logs:**

http://pastebin.com/WE4cMdaB

**Topology:**

python --- ESL --> Freeswitch -- sip-- Twilio ---> PSTN ---> fax

When I use:

```
originate loopback/9178 &txfax(/tmp/surface3d.tiff)
```

I do see Fax modules being invoked:

http://pastebin.com/9P2yJFWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute_on_fax_detect` is only for incoming calls to detect fax.
`originate loopback/9178 &txfax(/tmp/surface3d.tiff)` this you making call to loopback and on answer it starts transmitting tiff file. so you're seeing fax modules invoked. 
try `tone_detect` to see if you can achieve it.